# JSON Unterminated object at character

Tags: java, android, json

I want to read json from the internet and for now I can read it from the internet to string but I have probably made a mistake which i can't find in the json:

```
{
     "S4ROMS" :[
     {
        "name":"Cyanogenmod 13",
        "android":"6.0.1",
        "status":"nightly",
        "description":"If you like android, you probably can't wait till your phone gets updates but cyanogenmod 13 brings you not just original android 6.0.1, it comes with root access, option to apply themes, option to switch from hardware to on screen buttons, the rest you will know when you install it.",
        "tested":true,
        "website":"https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=jfltexx",
        "image":"http://images.technewstoday.com.s3.amazonaws.com/tnt/how-to-install-android-marshmallow-samsung-galaxy-s4-using-cm13-rom.jpg",
        "gapps":true
     },
     {
        "name":"S4 Google Edition",
        "android":"4.4.4",
        "status":"stable",
        "description":"Feel the experience of Nexus - this tells you everything.",
        "tested":false,
        "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2544474",
        "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",
        "gapps":false
     },
     {
        "name":"PhoeniX ROM v11.6",
        "android":"5.0.x",
        "status":"stable"
        "description":"Stock 5.0 Samsung Galaxy S4 touchwiz rom with some mods, hacks and addons.",
        "tested":true,
        "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2349584",
        "gapps":false
     },
     {
        "name":"Miui 7",
        "android":"4.4.x",
        "status":"stable with some bugs",
        "description":"Chinese rom based on Samsung Galaxy S4 with brand new UI looking like Iphone.",
        "tested":false,
        "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9505-develop/4-4-miui-7-t3184430",
        "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",
        "gapps":false
     },
     {
        "name":"AOKP",
        "android":"4.4.x",
        "status":"stable"
        "description":"AOSP based rom with some tweaks.",
        "tested":true,
        "website":"http://aokp.co/devices/jflte",
        "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",
        "gapps":true
     },
     {
        "name":"SOKP",
        "android":"4.4.x",
        "status":"stable",
        "description":"Cyanogen Mod 11.0 based rom with some tweaks.",
        "tested":false,
        "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2724109",
        "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",
        "gapps":true
     },
     {
        "name":"XenonHD",
        "android":"4.4.2",
        "status":"alpha 1",
        "description":"The idea behind XenonHD is to give users a ROM that is 'blazing fast, rock stable and battery smooth'. The ROM is based on AOSP.",
        "tested":false,
        "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2737839",
        "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",
        "gapps":true
     },
     {
        "name":"SlimSaberKat",
        "android":"4.4.4",
        "status":"stable",
        "description":"The ROM is based on SlimKat (AOSP).",
        "tested":false,
        "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2760650",
        "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",
        "gapps":true
     }
     ] 
  }
```

The java android code reads it from the intenrnet and if I delete everything except the first 2 jsonarrays it reads it too and gives the expected output but when I use all the json code it gives my this exception

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 1098 of {         "S4ROMS" :[         {            "name":"Cyanogenmod 13",            "android":"6.0.1",          "status":"nightly",         "description":"If you like android, you probably can't wait till your phone gets updates but cyanogenmod 13 brings you not just original android 6.0.1, it comes with root access, option to apply themes, option to switch from hardware to on screen buttons, the rest you will know when you install it.",           "tested":true,          "website":"https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=jfltexx",           "image":"http://images.technewstoday.com.s3.amazonaws.com/tnt/how-to-install-android-marshmallow-samsung-galaxy-s4-using-cm13-rom.jpg",         "gapps":true         },      {            "name":"S4 Google Edition",            "android":"4.4.4",         "status":"stable",          "description":"Feel the experience of Nexus - this tells you everything.",          "tested":false,         "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2544474",           "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",          "gapps":false         },         {            "name":"PhoeniX ROM v11.6",            "android":"5.0.x",         "status":"stable"           "description":"Stock 5.0 Samsung Galaxy S4 touchwiz rom with some mods, hacks and addons.",         "tested":true,          "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2349584",           "gapps":false         },         {            "name":"Miui 7",            "android":"4.4.x",            "status":"stable with some bugs",           "description":"Chinese rom based on Samsung Galaxy S4 with brand new UI looking like Iphone.",          "tested":false,         "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9505-develop/4-4-miui-7-t3184430",            "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",          "gapps":false         },         {            "name":"AOKP",            "android":"4.4.x",          "status":"stable"           "description":"AOSP based rom with some tweaks.",           "tested":true,          "website":"http://aokp.co/devices/jflte",           "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",          "gapps":true         },      {            "name":"SOKP",            "android":"4.4.x",          "status":"stable",          "description":"Cyanogen Mod 11.0 based rom with some tweaks.",          "tested":false,         "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2724109",           "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",          "gapps":true         },      {            "name":"XenonHD",            "android":"4.4.2",           "status":"alpha 1",         "description":"The idea behind XenonHD is to give users a ROM that is 'blazing fast, rock stable and battery smooth'. The ROM is based on AOSP.",           "tested":false,         "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2737839",           "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",          "gapps":true         },      {            "name":"SlimSaberKat",            "android":"4.4.4",          "status":"stable",          "description":"The ROM is based on SlimKat (AOSP).",            "tested":false,         "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2760650",           "image":"http://abload.de/img/1qzo3r.png",          "gapps":true         }         ]       }
```

Comment: missing a comma after some `status` field, also you can use online json validator

Comment: An online json validator like this one: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following pics show cause of error.............in your code
[image]

missing comma  here...

Answer (score 4):

In the block for `PhoeniX ROM v11.6` there is a missing comma after `status`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the json object values contains quotes like "stable""description":"Stock 5.0 Samsung Galaxy S4 touchwiz rom with some mods, hacks and addons.", "tested":true, "website":"http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2349584", "gapps":false

paste it into a json parser/validitor reveals the errors
http://json.parser.online.fr/